# Why win32com.client dont work after successful installation?

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, win32com

I'm working on project in python, and I need to get access to Outlook.

I tried every solution that was suggested in the past questions on that topic, but nothing works.

Installed pywin32 and pypiwin32, they appear in pip list.

But still cant import "win32com.client" to my project, same error as before:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'.

Things I've tried:

1. Installing with pip as said before.
2. I tried to install "pywin32" from:

https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases

3. Running the command: python pywin32_postinstall.py -install in the python directory.

All of this installs was successfull, but the "import win32com.client" not working.

**EDIT:**

I updated my pip version in project interpreter:

Pycharm > file> settings> project>project interpreter

and after this, installed the "pypiwin32" with project interpreter, finally it solved the problem.

Comment: which version of Python are you using? Did you make sure you installed the package for the version  of Python you're importing it from?

Comment: Python 3.8.2 32 bit version, yes, I've installed "pywin32-227.win32-py3.8.exe" from the https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases